# SQL Trigger after insert not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2016

I tried to write a trigger that updates the data after an insert.
I'm using the SQL Server 2016 Import Export Data tool to transfer my data from Excel into the database.
After the import I need to run a few update statements.
I can save my trigger, but it's not updating any data. Where is my fault?

Trigger:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_InsertMappinng]
   ON  [dbo].[T_CCG_MBR2017_Across]
   AFTER  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE  [DB_CC_FC_Database_SQL].[dbo].[T_CCG_MBR2017_Across] 
    SET [Colum1] = 'Text1' 
    Where [Colum1] IS NULL 
    AND [Colum2] = 'Text2' 
    AND [Colum3] = 'Text3' 
    AND [Colum4] = 'Text4'


END
```

Comment: does this query UPDATE  [DB_CC_FC_Database_SQL].[dbo].[T_CCG_MBR2017_Across] SET [Colum1] = 'Text1' 
    Where [Colum1] IS NULL AND [Colum2] = 'Text2' AND [Colum3] = 'Text3' AND [Colum4] = 'Text4'
 do something when used outside trigger ?

Comment: Yes, it works when I run it without the trigger!

Comment: Select all the Inserted value In A Variable And Then Update IT.how this works for you

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this helps. I just used a simple insert statement and my trigger works perfectly. It just doesn't work with the data import tool...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116848/after-insert-trigger-never-fires-using-import-wizard), th SQL Import Export Data Tool doesn't fire any trigger. You can find more information about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/bulk-import-and-export-of-data-sql-server).

Answer (score 1):

If your code is working outside the trigger, but not within the trigger, it could just be that the trigger is disabled. Try enabling it, and run it again to test.

```
ENABLE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_InsertMappinng]
    ON [dbo].[T_CCG_MBR2017_Across];
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't change anything. Seems like the data import doen't count as an insert.

Comment: I just used a simple insert statement and the trigger works perfectly. It just doesn't work with the data import tool...